# Convert SQL to LINQ/EF

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework, linq

I want to convert this SQL query to LINQ. But I'm new in EF. Please help

SQL Query

```
select * from VersionHistory where id in( select OptionsId from StylesHistory where ConId=540 and OptionsId = 28286 and ModifiedAtVersion>1)
```

TIA

I tried Something like this

```
var stylesHistory = _context.VersionHistory
    .Where(x => x.ModifiedAtVersion > 1 
                 && x.Id==28286 
                 && x.Contract.Id==540)
    .ToList()
```

Not Sure How I can add Sub Query

Comment: Your question is getting downvoted as you haven't shown  any effort. At least show what you've tried and the errors you got, or why the behaviour wasn't as you expected.

Comment: Share your attempts with us and we would be happy to help.  We also need to see your schema and models.  Without these things, your question will probably be closed, as right now it sounds like a "give me the code" question, and those never go over well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily write that as:

```
var result = ctx.VersionHistory
  .Where(vh => ctx.StylesHistory
         .Any( sh => sh.OptionsId == vh.Id &&
                sh.OptionsId == 28286 &&
                sh.ConId = 540 &&
                sh.ModifiedAtVersion > 1));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also create your subquery as another IEnumerable which you'll use in the main query.

This will improve readibility.

EF will only generate one query.